# Sencha Touch: setValue on TextField does not work

Tags: sencha-touch

In Sencha Touch 2 I have a controller which calls a custom 'prepopulate' method on button tap:

```
Ext.Ajax.request
    ({  
        method: 'GET',
        url:  myurl, //defined outside
        withCredentials: true,
        headers:{Authorization : auth},
        success: function(response){

            var data; 

            if(response.responseText.length > 0)
                  data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText.trim());

            console.log(data);

            var fv = me.getFiscal();

            console.log(fv);

            fv.prepopulate(data);

            Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem('fiscal', me.getSlideLeftTransition());
        },
        failure: function(response){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Server Error', 'Server down :( please try again later');
        }
    }


    );
```

View code:

```
prepopulate : function (data) {

    var me = this;


    var companyTextField = me.down('#fiscalForm').down('#companyTextField');
    var vatField = me.down('#fiscalForm').down('#vatField');

    var fiscalCodeTextField = me.down('#fiscalForm').down('#fiscalCodeTextField');
    var addressTextField = me.down('#fiscalForm').down('#addressTextField');

    var cityTextField = me.down('#fiscalForm').down('#cityTextField');
    var zipTextField = me.down('#fiscalForm').down('#zipTextField');

    var countryTextField = me.down('#fiscalForm').down('#countryTextField');
    console.log(vatField);
    console.log((data.vat));
    if(data){

        if(data.company_name)
            companyTextField.setValue(data.company_name);
        if(data.vat)
            vatField.setValue(data.vat);
        if(data.fiscal_code)
            fiscalCodeTextField.setValue(data.fiscal_code);
        if(data.address)
            addressTextField.setValue(data.address);
        if(data.city)
            cityTextField.setValue(data.city);
        if(data.zip)
            zipTextField.setValue(data.zip);
        if(data.country)
            countryTextField.setValue(data.country);

    }
    console.log(vatField);
}
```

The AJAX call works fine and it calls on success the prepopulate method passing the data retrieved from the server.
I try to initialize the TextFields using setValue() but the form looks 'brand new' when I open it using the browser
console.log() tells me that the _value private field is correctly set though... I'm groping in the dark right now ... any insight?

Thank You in advance.

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggest the data i correctly retrieved and display in the console with the console.log, nonetheless the browser don't find any visible fields to modify the value when the setValue() is called.

The solution so far is to modify the ajax request as follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request
({  
....
....
    success: function(response){
    ....
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem('fiscal', me.getSlideLeftTransition());

                    //view must be in the viewport before modifying data:
        var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function () {
                var fv = me.getFiscal();
                fv.prepopulate(data);
        });
        task.delay(1000);
.....
....
...
..
.
```

Comment: Hm, I would not really call this a solution (no offence meant). Waiting an arbitrary time and then setting the values is a bit of a race-condition prone hack. Personally I would use setValues on the form component instead of manually setting the values of individual fields. When using setValues it does not matter if the form is not rendered yet. So give the fields a 'name' property and refer to that name in the object to pass to setValues. An alternative is to create a model instance and use setRecord.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out on sencha, there must have been some more robust solution:) it looks like it